# Which is easier to integrate?

Tags: calculus, integration

My calculus teacher gave us this problem in class:

Which is easier to integrate?

$$\int \sin^{100}x\cos x dx$$

or

$$\int \sin^{50}xdx$$

By easier, I assume the teacher means which integral would take less work. I'm unsure of how to approach this problem because of the relatively large exponents. I would guess the second because it has smaller exponents but I'm not sure.

Comment: Change $\cos x \  dx$ to $d\sin x$, and it is clear that which one is easier.

Comment: I think the teacher hopes you will quickly recognize how the chain rule helps you do the first one.

Comment: Hint: I did one mentally in ten seconds and the other would take me a quarter of an hour on paper.

Comment: Does anyone want to explain why this was downvoted? I thought this was a very interesting question for an introductin to basic integration techniques.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which would you prefer to do?

Let $u=\sin x$ and $du=\cos  x$, transforming the integral into $\displaystyle \int  u^{100} du$.

Or use the reduction formula: $\displaystyle\int \sin^n x dx=\frac{-\sin^{n-1}x \cos x}{n}+\frac{n-1}{n}\int \sin^{n-2}x dx$ for $n=50$? I found the formula [here](http://www.vias.org/calculus/07_trigonometric_functions_05_03.html).

Of course, both can be done, but the reduction formula is incredibly tedious to use. The power rule of integration is much simpler.

Comment: Why can't you use the same substitution for the second one?

Comment: Because the $du$ expression does not appear in the second integral. This is the key to the problem, because you're essentially reversing the chain rule, by finding the derivative of a function which appears in the integrand.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, the first one.
$$\int \sin^{100}x \cos x \,\, dx=\int \sin^{100}x \, \,d(\sin x)=\frac{\sin^{101}x}{101}+c$$

And the other integral requires more than *just* $2$ steps. You may try any method you like.It cannot be rigorously proved that the integral requires more than *just* $2$ steps.

Comment: It sounds like the OP does not understand that the second one requires more than two steps, so I'm not sure this is obvious.

Comment: The tone of this answer is condescending to the OP. If it were "obvious" to the OP, they wouldn't have asked the question.

Comment: @J.Loreaux Tone changed. Is it okay now?

Comment: I mean, it still has the word "obviously," but I appreciate the consideration of removing the other instance of "obvious." I have removed my downvote.